# For-Loop PeopleCode Array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, peoplesoft, peoplecode

Is it possible to loop for two array statements? I am trying to put it on display just to see if I will be getting the correct values, but it turned out it that my code is only working for single statement:

Here's the code (not working):

```
&DelFrom = CreateArray();
&DelTo = CreateArray();


For &del_from = 1 To &DelFrom.Len
And &del_to = 1 To &DelTo.Len

Warning MsgGet (0, 0, &DelFrom [&del_from] "-" &DelTo [&del_to]);

End-For;
```

Here's the other one (working, but for only the **del_from** for example):

```
For &del_from = 1 To &DelFrom.Len

Warning MsgGet (0, 0, &DelFrom [&del_from]);

End-For;
```

Comment: Never used peoplesoft or peoplecode--in fact, just learnt about it from your post. In modern imperative languages, it's generally possible to nest one 'for' loop within another. Have you thought about doing that?

Comment: Yes, however we just have to use only peoplecode on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't loop on two different iterators within the same `for` loop, but you can nest loops.

```
For &del_from = 1 To &DelFrom.Len
   For &del_to = 1 To &DelTo.Len
      Warning MsgGet (0, 0, &DelFrom [&del_from] "-" &DelTo [&del_to]);
   End-For;
End-For;
```

This will get you every permutation of values from `&DelFrom` and `&DelTo` within you loop body.  Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did try this one and it works! Thank you!